# interpolation between two curves in R

Tags: r, interpolation, approximation, curves

I have two curves of same count of points filled using approx function, for both x and y values separately for each curve. Both x and y axis values are logarithmic, so I convert back to normal decimal scale when approximating and interpolating. Black and blue lines are original lines and the red one is interpolated in between. As you can see the red line doesn't mimic the bend on the right side, since interpolation is performed based on assumption that each x and y pair are the closest.

Is there any way how to perform interpolation between curves in R based on the real closest points in between? Maybe there exists algorithms for that? Anything would be useful as I am not sure how it is called in mathematics.

```
    base="ftp://cdsarc.u-strasbg.fr/pub/cats/J/A+A/508/355/ms/"
    setwd("~/Desktop")
    file1=paste(base,"z001y23_1.60.dat",sep="")
    file2=paste(base,"z001y23_1.70.dat",sep="")

    cols=c("no","age","logL","logTef", "grav","stage")
    ncol <- length(count.fields(file=file1, sep = ","))
    second=read.table(file=file1,fill=T, blank.lines.skip=F, skip=2, header=F, strip.white=T, col.names = paste("V", seq_len(ncol)))
    second$V.6<-second$V.23
    colnames(second) <-cols
    second$logL=as.numeric(second$logL)
    #performing some filtering of data here
    pos1=which(second$stage == "trgb")[1]
    second=second[1:pos1,]

    ncol <- length(count.fields(file=file2, sep = ","))
    first=read.table(file=file2,fill=T, blank.lines.skip=F, skip=2, header=F, strip.white=T, col.names = paste("V", seq_len(ncol)))
    first$V.6<-first$V.23
    colnames(first) <-cols
    #performing some filtering of data here
    pos2=which(first$stage == "trgb")[1]
    first=first[1:pos2,]

    #plotting data
    len=max(c(min(first[[4]]),min(second[[4]])))
    first=first[first[[4]]>len,]
    second=second[second[[4]]>len,]

    plot(second[[4]],second[[3]],t="l",xlim=rev(range(second[[4]])),xlab="x",ylab="y")
    lines(first[[4]],first[[3]],t="l",col="blue")
    n=max(c(length(second[[4]]),length(first[[4]])))
    #approximating missing points
    xf1 <- approx(10^second[[4]],n=n)
    yf1 <- approx(10^second[[3]],n=n)

    xf2 <- approx(10^first[[4]],n=n)
    yf2 <- approx(10^first[[3]],n=n)

    #calculating interpolated line
    ratio=2
    s1<-log10((xf1$y-xf2$y)/ratio+xf2$y)
    s2<-log10((yf1$y-yf2$y)/ratio+yf2$y)
    lines(s1,s2, col ="red")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

<del>While not the ultimate answer,</del> here is something adapted from what I did a while ago for stream channel migration. Note that those are usually not self crossing so your mileage may vary. The whole idea is to calculate curvatures and use [dynamic time warping](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dtw/index.html) to match extrema.

Roughly it can be summarize like that:

1. Parametrize both curves so L1 and L2 are vectors representing lengths from curve beginning to the index in question.
2. Calculate `smooth.spline` xsp1, ysp1, xsp2, ysp2 using L1 and L2 for x and y of each curve. Pay attention to smoothing parameter as your curves look sharp at times.
3. [Explicitly](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/predict.smooth.spline.html) get [signed curvature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Signed_curvature) for each smoothed line
4. Use dtw to match peaks in curvatures of each smoothed line
5. Use indices returned by dtw to establish mapping between curves
6. ...
7. PROFIT!!!

Note that dtw does not do miracles, and some experimentation would be necessary.

P.S. To save your time, I tried to use dtw directly on x & y without curvatures, but it didn't turn out nice as we'd want mapping for both coordinates at the same time.

**EDIT**

```
library(dtw)
df1 <- data.frame(x=first[[4]], y=first[[3]])
df2 <- data.frame(x=second[[4]], y=second[[3]])
measure <- function(df)
  within(df, m <- c(0, cumsum(diff(x)^2 + diff(y)^2)))
df1 <- measure(df1)
df2 <- measure(df2)

curvify <- function(df) {
  xsp <- with(df, smooth.spline(m, x))
  ysp <- with(df, smooth.spline(m, y))
  xx <- predict(xsp, df$m)$y
  yy <- predict(ysp, df$m)$y
  xp <- predict(xsp, df$m, deriv=1)$y
  xpp <- predict(xsp, df$m, deriv=2)$y
  yp <- predict(ysp, df$m, deriv=1)$y
  ypp <- predict(ysp, df$m, deriv=2)$y
  # http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Signed_curvature
  within(df, c <- (xp*ypp - yp*xpp)/(xp^2 + yp^2)^1.5)
}

df1 <- curvify(df1)
df2 <- curvify(df2)

d <- dtw(df1$c, df2$c, keep=TRUE)
# plot(d, type='three')

xx <- ( df1$x[d$index1] + df2$x[d$index2] ) /2
yy <- ( df1$y[d$index1] + df2$y[d$index2] ) /2

lines(xx, yy, col="green")
```

[image]

[image]

EDIT

To interpolate with weights other than 1/2

```
fr <- 1/3
xx <- df1$x[d$index1] * fr + df2$x[d$index2] * (1-fr)
yy <- df1$y[d$index1] * fr + df2$y[d$index2] * (1-fr)
lines(xx, yy, col="yellow")

fr <- 2/3
xx <- df1$x[d$index1] * fr + df2$x[d$index2] * (1-fr)
yy <- df1$y[d$index1] * fr + df2$y[d$index2] * (1-fr)
lines(xx, yy, col="brown")
```

Comment: I just realized that I forgot *sqrt* for euclidean distance, but nevertheless result looks okay to me and get ugly with that... oh well... lazy to look at that. Perhaps it affects smoothening defaults.

Comment: You may accept it as an answer if it works for you. Also note that it matches curvature and not the closest points, so curves should exhibit similar turns.

Comment: That exactly what I needed. So it is good enough, just adjusted the 1.5 weigth to lower one and it seems all good.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the arbitrary fraction interpolation.